# Are there any resources to find modern (or effective) assignment types, knowledge control techniques?

Tags: publications, online-learning, assessment, course-design

I'm participating in creating blended (online/offline) courses. Faced a problem of inventing well-designed assignments/assessments. There are already quizzes, essays valuated by teacher, webinars/live lessons. But they are usual, they don't involve students.

So I started searching for teachers' experiences in more unusual ways to control students' knowledge, gather information about each student. But it is very scattered.

**Can anyone advice some resources (sites, publications, works, magazines) about this topic?** I'm absolutely new in education, so any help will be appreciated.

A bit more information about courses:

- oriented on graduate, under-graduate levels and professional development
- 2 levels of audience: medium (60-100 members in a moment) and big (close to MOOCs: 100-thousands).
- technical difficult is not limited

Answer (score 1):

The number of students in each blended course is definitely a consideration when creating effective assignments and assessments of student learning, however, **the most important consideration** is the student learning outcomes (SLOs) - what are students expected to do, think, or know by the end of your course?  The SLOs will direct the design of the assignments, as well as the assessments of student learning, for your course. Here is a very short training to help you learn to create assignments and assessments from student learning outcomes: http://jeandowns.weebly.com/  There are additional resources and references at the end of the training.